# Network Discovery Tool

Tags: networking, discovery

I'm currently working at a Company which has many Seats through the country. Currently we are looking for a Network Discovery Tool which lists all Servers, Switches, Computers... in our Network.

Found a few tools like Portnox, Cacti and Icinga; But these are to complexe for our needs.

Hope somedy can help us out

Cheers

Comment: This question is off-topic for a couple of reasons, including: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [netTransformer](https://github.com/iTransformers/netTransformer)? Here is the [user guide](http://itransformers.net/UserGuide-Pirin.pdf). You can download it from sourceforge or directly from the github.